# Angularjs with Ionic not see $scope.variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Does anyone would be able to explain to me why $scope does not have a variable?

If you enter something in the input it can be seen that the variable is displayed, but if you open a console, where I try to show by console.log is a variable with $scope.presearch is empty ''.

How do we get rid of the directives of the ionic it all works, so I suspect that he somehow insulates scope

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Ionic Seed App</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.css">

      <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/ionic.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>


      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <!--<script src="controllers.js"></script>-->
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="mobile-menu sidebar-left">
                Menu
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-content overflow-scroll='true'>

        <input type="text" style="border:1px solid black;" ng-model="presearch" ng-keyup="autoKeyUp()">
        <h1><b>{{presearch}}</b></h1>
    </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
    </ion-side-menus>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ionic']);
app.controller('AppCtrl',['$rootScope','$scope', function($rootScope,$scope){
  $scope.autoKeyUp = function() {
    console.log($scope.presearch);
  }
}]);
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/fh7WtJCs5S7R7iNXyfXM/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your plunkr example is, that you never include your controller. you can do this for example with

```
 <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" style="padding:20px;">
```

Or better to use `$stateProvider`

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        });  
});
```

**EDIT**

The problem is, that `ion-content` has his own `$scope` and therefore the 2 way data-binding doesn't work anymore. see http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/. It works if you add your controller to the `ion-content` element:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I don't know why it opened another page. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 2 way data binding wrks based on update by refernce to an object, use an object instead of primitive value to assign the ng-model.

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll='true'>
    <input type="text" style="border:1px solid black;" ng-model="model.presearch" ng-keyup="autoKeyUp()">
    <h1><b>{{model.presearch}}</b></h1>
</ion-content>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.autoKeyUp = function() {
  console.log($scope.model.presearch);
}
```